# How to fix the NDK build error: pread failed: Is a directory?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I got the following error when i build some native codes on android:

```
/Users/jerikc/Library/Android/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: fatal error: /Users/jerikc/workdir/workspace/projuect: pread failed: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The ndk version is: r10d

The Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := libpng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libpng.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += \
    libpng
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libjpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libjpeg.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += \
    libjpeg
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libcrypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcrypto.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := processing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += filter_jni.c \
        control.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g -O3 -ffast-math
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lm -lz
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libpng  libjpeg libcrypto

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $(CLEAR_VARS) to clean up your local variables, on which make is working now.

Here is the link, where you can find some useful info about it: [http://android.mk/](http://Android.mk)

I assume, that following version will solve your problem. I don't have system to check it right now.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libpng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libpng.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += \
    libpng
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libjpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libjpeg.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += \
    libjpeg
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libcrypto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcrypto.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := processing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += filter_jni.c \
        control.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g -O3 -ffast-math
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lm -lz
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libpng  libjpeg libcrypto

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```